# Match words (regex) and create internal links from values stored in Array

Tags: php, regex

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
When I create news items, I want php to check these items for keywords. These keywords are stored in a mysql table (2 fields: search = varchar(255), link = varchar(255)).
I use a query to get the results and store them in an array.

I want to find words in a string and add an anchor to the word. The important bit is (where I have difficulty with) is that the search has to be case insensitive.

For example:

```
$searchFor = array("sun","sunny","wind","crap");
$linkArray = array("/solar","/solar","/wind-energy","/toilet");
```

The string:

> What do you know about the sun? Sun, what kind of word is that? Is it
>   something just like wind? Wind, another weird word. This text is
>   complete crap by the way.

What I want as a result is:

> What do you know about the [sun](/solar)? [Sun](/solar) what kind of word is that? Is it something just like [wind](/wind-energy)? [Wind](/wind-energy) another weird word. This text is complete [crap](/toilet) by the way.

The code I have is:

```
$string = 'What do you know about the sun? Sun, what kind of word is that? Is it something just like wind? Wind, another weird word. This text is complete crap by the way.';
$pattern = "/(\w+)/i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $i => $word)
{
    $search = strtolower($word);
    if(in_array($search,$searchFor))
    {
        $pos = array_search($search,$searchFor);
        $link = $linkArray[$pos];
        echo "<a href=\"{$link}\">{$word}</a> ";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $word." ";
    }
}
```

But I get stuck using regex (I think this is the right way).

```
$replacement = '<a href="{$link}">${1}</a>';
```

Is this possible??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Testet!**

```
<?php
$searchFor = array("sun","sunny","wind","crap");
foreach($searchFor as $iKey => $sVal) {
    $searchFor[$iKey] = "/(" . $sVal . ")/i";
}
$linkArray = array("/solar","/solar","/wind-energy","/toilet");
foreach($linkArray as $iKey => $sVal) {
    $linkArray[$iKey] = '<a href="' . $sVal . '">$1</a>';
}
$string = 'What do you know about the sun? Sun, what kind of word is that? Is it something just like wind? Wind, another weird word. This text is complete crap by the way.';
echo preg_replace($searchFor, $linkArray, $string);
```